GDB debugger terminates after using step over
I'm using visual studio code (1.93.1) along with GDB debugger (15.1) and g++ compiler (14.2.0) on windows.
Whenever I use a breakpoint and try to click the step-over button, the debugger stops working, but doesn't terminate (there's a gif explaining what happens below)
for context here's my tasks.json:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}


I've tried reinstalling the compiler and debugger multiple times with no success, everything in the debugger works except for this functionality.
Edit: here's a code example that causes this problem:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int mod (int b, int p, int m)
{
    if (p==0) return 1;
    if (p%2==0)
    {
        int r = mod(b,p/2,m);
        return (r*r)%m;   
    } else {
        return (b%m*mod(b,p-1,m))%m;   
    }
}


int main()
{
    int T; scanf("%d", &T);
    while (T--)
    {
        int b,p,m; cin >> b >> p >> m;
        printf("%d\n", mod(b,p,m));
    }
}

By using this as input
1
18132
17
17

And putting a braekpoint on line 8 and using step over, it breaks.

I don't see a gif.

@ssbssa it seemed to not have been uploaded correctly, now i've added it

The gif is somewhat blurry, so it's not super clear, but I'm going to assume you're trying to allocate a very large vector, which the debugger then for some reason can't handle. To sort this out properly, you'd need to post (part of) your code. What's the value of W*H-1? The debugger hint says something about a length of ~209320767?
There are a few issues that may or may not be related; https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76798, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11662, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7240.

@jtunhag I've edited it and added a code example if you would like to see it.

Quoted from this
The Gui debug hang is solved by added the following to the launch.json file:
"setupCommands": [
{
"description": "Disable target async",
"text": "set target-async off",
"ignoreFailures": true
}


In my experience this can sometimes happen in the event of a Segfault. Is it possible that you are accessing freed memory or attempting to dereference some null value? I don't have experience with VSCode debugging, but in other IDE's I have had this happen frequently (using GDB ).

doesn't seem to be the reason, without breakpoints the program runs normally but with breakpoints it always does that.
